# Why do MacOS mail junk mail rules and filters not work on emails that fail Apple's DMARC policy?

Tags: macos, email

While exploring why none of my MacOS mail junk Mal rules and filters do not work I contacted Apple support. Which a bit of prodding my question was forwarded to an engineering team and received the following answer:

"According to review, it was determined that a DMARC policy is in effect that instructs us to quarantine any message from your domain that fails DMARC."

The support person also said that if an email fails the Apple DMARC policy the email is ignored by the MacOS Mail Rules and Filters. It appears that emails that fail the DMARC policy are quarantined and moved into the Junk mail folder.

Does anyone know of a way to post process junk emails once they are dumped into the Junk folder?

I am wondering if it is possible to write a Mail extension to accomplish this task?

Comment: From which perspective are you approaching this; the recipient of mail messages or as the sender of these messages (from an Apple domain like @mac or @icloud)?

Comment: I get tons of junk mail that is easy to write rules for but apparently (according to Apple) are quarantined (and moved to my Junk mail folder) by Apple's DMARC profile before any MacOS mail rules or filters can be applied. Since I end up with a bunch of emails in my Junk folder I have to manually block delete them which can sometimes include non-junk emails that sometimes end up in my Junk folder.

Answer (score 1):

> The support person also said that if an email fails the Apple DMARC policy the email is ignored by the MacOS Mail Rules and Filters. It appears that emails that fail the DMARC policy are quarantined and moved into the Junk mail folder.

#### This is correct.

The short answer is that Apple has a [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) policy that states messages that don't conform to their policy will be immediately be quarantined.

#### What is DMARC...

[DMARC or Domain-based Message Authentication, Reporting and Conformance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) is an email authentication protocol designed to help mitigae SPAM, [Phishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing) and other email based attacks.

Basically,  a recipient email server can do a number of actions like look up the DNS record for "instructions" on how to authenticate the sender, make sure it conforms to accepted standards ([RFC-5322](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322)), and how they handle both bulk mail and individual transactions; this is just a small sample.

#### Apple's Policy...

Apple's policy is that when it doesn't comply with their policy is to immediately quarantine.  Email marketing firms discuss this at length: [How Apple’s DMARC Changes Affect Email Senders](https://sendgrid.com/blog/how-apples-dmarc-changes-affect-email-senders/)

Apple provides a support document for System Administrators who manage mail servers that bulk mail to Apple owned domains (icloud.com, me.com, mac.com).  See [Postmaster information for iCloud Mail](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204137).

> Does anyone know of a way to post process junk emails once they are dumped into the Junk folder?
>
> I am wondering if it is possible to write a Mail extension to accomplish this task?

Not likely.  There are two types of (server based) rules:  global and per user.  Global rules are processed system-wide and take priority over user-based rules.  This is a security consideration not one of convenience.  When dealing with bulk senders and the Apple mail servers must deal with millions of emails coming in that don't conform to their policy, the safest action (and most prudent, IMO) is to "lock it down" (quarantine).

To put this another way, Apple is taking a "fail safe" approach here and allowing rules to bypass this would (IMO) be counterintuitive.

Comment: I guess I'll have to write my own Mail extension to handle this.

Comment: Plus what's the point if the quarantined email ends up in the users Junk folder?